# Why do we have a 200 reputation/day limit?

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit

Why do we have a 200 reputation/day limit? 
Is 200 any *magical* number? Why do we limit it at all?

Comment: Why not? What's your suggestion? What's a better limit and why?

Comment: Why should we limit it at all?

Comment: To get back in real life after reaching the limit.

Comment: So people who are after reputation can get a rest - don't want to have people dying from too much Stack Overflow, as some gamers do.

Comment: Another reason for the rate limiting is to keep someone who asks a question that gets posted on Reddit and gets an insane number of views in 1 day from getting too much rep from a [single question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14415881/250725)

Comment: Because we don't want Reddit users to one day swarm on and upvote Jon skeet to a rep of 73,382,100,383,100,123

Comment: @Michael - It's limited because otherwise certain users would obsess over it

Comment: @Adel It's a good thing nobody obsesses over rep thanks to the rep cap.